# Return the array index of an element containing the closest matching value in Python

Tags: python, arrays

How do I return the index for the array element whose sub-element value is the closest matching Int to my query.

eg:
If the array looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
      {
        "time": 1483304400,
      },
      {
        "time": 1483308000,
      },
      {
        "time": 1483311600,
      },
      {
        "time": 1483315200,
      },
      {
        "time": 1483318800,
      }
    ]
}
```

and my query is `1483311700` then I want to return `2` as that's the index for the closest matching element.

Comment: this is a dictionary , you can look it like a json , use a library like demjson , then decode it using this instruction , `demjson.decode(String that containing the input)` then look it like an array , use a for loop , then calculate the most close number to your expected number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using the built-in [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function with a custom key function that returns the absolute difference between the value of a `'time'` key and `query`.

`min(it, key=keyfunc)` returns the smallest element from `it` according to `keyfunc`. If you use [`enumerate(it)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of `it` and tweak the key function accordingly, `min` will return both the element and its index:

```
>>> index, value = min(enumerate(data), key=lambda x:abs(x[1]['time'] - query))
>>> index
2
```

Here `data` is the value of the `'data'` key in your input.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using `bisect.bisect(a, x, lo=0, hi=len(a))` function(*returns an insertion point which comes after (to the right of) any existing entries of x in a.*):

```
idx = bisect.bisect([d['time'] for d in data], 1483311700) - 1
print(idx)  # 2
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect

Answer (score 0):

Isolate the time values in a list.

```
In [1]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:data = {
:  "data": [
:      {
:        "time": 1483304400,
:      },
:      {
:        "time": 1483308000,
:      },
:      {
:        "time": 1483311600,
:      },
:      {
:        "time": 1483315200,
:      },
:      {
:        "time": 1483318800,
:      }
:    ]
:}
:--

In [2]: data["data"]
Out[2]: 
[{'time': 1483304400},
 {'time': 1483308000},
 {'time': 1483311600},
 {'time': 1483315200},
 {'time': 1483318800}]

In [3]: times = [j["time"] for j in data["data"]]

In [4]: times
Out[4]: [1483304400, 1483308000, 1483311600, 1483315200, 1483318800]
```

Then generate a list of the absolute difference between the list items and your query.

```
In [3]: times = [j["time"] for j in data["data"]]

In [4]: times
Out[4]: [1483304400, 1483308000, 1483311600, 1483315200, 1483318800]

In [5]: diff = [abs(j-1483311700) for j in times]

In [6]: diff
Out[6]: [7300, 3700, 100, 3500, 7100]
```

Last, find the index of the lowest difference.

```
In [7]: min(diff)
Out[7]: 100

In [8]: diff.index(100)
Out[8]: 2
```